# After installing ionic mobile app in device it shows Error connection time out

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I installed the mobile application in a device(android). it shows an error connection timed out. It's an ionic 3 project. And we used the rest API also.

[image]

Help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added internet permission in manifest file? and try to increase loadUrlTmeValue in your `config.xml`

Comment: i already added [ <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />]. @Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the problem. I tried using 'ionic cordova run andriod' so only this issue occurs. when i tried 'ionic cordova build android' issue solved